# No FtpWebRequest.GetResponse with IIS 7.5 and Firewall on but with Visual Studio 2010 Webserver and IIS Express 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, firewall, iis-express, ftpwebrequest

A MVC4 application downloads files from a FTP-Server in a action from HomeController. With the visual Studio 2010 Webserver and the local webserver IIS Express 8 it works.
But when I use the local webserver IIS 7.5 with ApplicationPoolIdenty, the download doesn't work: I don't received a respond on the line with the command "response = reqFTP.GetResponse()" and follow exception appears: "The operation has timed out").

When I switch off the Windows-Firewall, it works. What I need to do?

```
Function FtpStart() As ActionResult
        Dim downloadFiles As String()
        Dim result As New StringBuilder()
        Dim response As WebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
        Try
            Dim reqFTP As FtpWebRequest
            reqFTP = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri("ftp://adress")),FtpWebRequest)
            reqFTP.UseBinary = True
            reqFTP.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pw")
            reqFTP.EnableSsl = False
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
            reqFTP.Proxy = Nothing
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = False
            reqFTP.UsePassive = False
            Debug.WriteLine("Get Response: ")
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse()
            Debug.WriteLine("Response received")
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            While line IsNot Nothing
                result.Append(line)
                result.Append(vbLf)
                line = reader.ReadLine()
                Debug.WriteLine("File: " & line)
            End While
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf(ControlChars.Lf), 1)
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

ran into this issue earlier today myself on my web server.  You have to setup a rule on your firewall for inbound rules on TCP for ports 20 and 21.  It should show Local port = all ports, and remote ports = 20-21.  Also make sure that on the advanced tab, all three checkmarks are checked for domain, private, and public.  My firewall already had a FTP firewall rule for port 21, but not 20, as soon as I set the rule for port 20, it worked.

Hope this helps